# Spectral decomposition of a $4\times4$ real nonsymmetric matrix with unknown elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Given $\alpha>\beta>0$ and $\gamma>0$, find $Q$ and $\Lambda$ such that
>   $$
>    A = \begin{bmatrix}
>           -\alpha & \alpha & -\gamma^{-1} & 0\\
>           \beta & -\beta & 0 & -\gamma^{-1}\\
>           -1 & 0 & \alpha & -\beta\\
>           0 & -1 & -\alpha & \beta
>        \end{bmatrix}=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}
> $$

Since this is a homework exercise, I think there is a smart way to find the eigendecomposition of $A$.

Notice that

- $A$ is a Hamiltonian matrix, i.e. $JA$ is symmetric where $J=\begin{pmatrix}0 & I_2 \\ -I_2 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, $I_2$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix.
- The characteristic polynomial of a real Hamiltonian matrix is even. Thus, if $λ$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $−λ$, $\bar λ$ and $−\bar λ$ are also eigenvalues. It follows that $\text{trace} A=0$.
- $A$ can be written in block notation: $A=\begin{pmatrix}B & -\gamma^{-1}I_2 \\ -I_2 & -B^T \end{pmatrix}$, with $B=\begin{pmatrix}-\alpha & \alpha \\ \beta & -\beta\end{pmatrix}$.
- the elements on the antidiagonal are all $0$.
- sum of row $1$, sum of row $2$, sum of column $3$ and sum of column $4$ are all equal to $-\gamma^{-1}$.
- sum of row $3$ and sum of column $2$ are equal to $\alpha-\beta-1$.
- sum of row $4$ and sum of column $1$ are equal to $\beta-\alpha-1$.

can we use these facts to find $Q$ and $\Lambda$ more quickly?

Moreover, the characteristic polynomial is
$$
   p_A(\lambda) = \lambda^4-[(\alpha+\beta)^2+2\gamma^{-1}]\lambda^2+\gamma^{-1}(2\alpha^2+2\beta^2+\gamma^{-1})
$$
hence
$$
   2\lambda^2 = (\alpha+\beta)^2+2\gamma^{-1} \pm \sqrt{(\alpha+\beta)^4-4\gamma^{-1}(\alpha-\beta)^2}
$$
and the eigenvalues are either real or complex depending on the values of the parameters.

Comment: All the real numbers are complex. You meant $$\lambda\in\mathbb R\;\lor\;\lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$$

Comment: Also, you can see $\operatorname{trace}A=-\alpha-\beta+\alpha+\beta =0$ in the very beginng.

Comment: Since $\Lambda$ and $A$ are similar, they have the same characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya $\det A = \gamma^{-1}(2\alpha^2+2\beta^2+\gamma^{-1}) \ne 0$ in general

Comment: sorry, fair enough, I should've been more careful when looking at the given matrix.

Comment: Which method did you use to calculate the determinant? Maybe it can also shorten the process.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya I simply used the usual Laplace expansion method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion I used it also to compute $p_A(\lambda)$

Comment: I hope after row and column transformations?

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya no I use it directly on $A$, was it bad?

Comment: No, it just takes more time (: So, I hope you can do more things taking as much time as it took